# I migrated from hibernate 5 to hibernate 6 and using tomcat 10. Getting error

Tags: hibernate, migration

SEVERE: Servlet [dispatcher] in web application [/myApp] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ClassLoaderDelegate

Comment: Please read [ask]